# Virtualbox kernel vboxdrv not loaded on ubuntu 19.10

Tags: kernel, virtualbox, vagrant

i have installed virtualbox with repo

```
deb [arch=amd64] https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian aeon contrib

sudo apt-get install virtualbox vagrant -y
```

but use

```
VBoxManage --version
```

this error below

> ```
>    WARNING: The vboxdrv kernel module is not loaded. Either there is no module
>      available for the current kernel (5.3.0-45-generic) or it failed to
>      load. Please recompile the kernel module and install it by
> ```

```
       sudo /sbin/vboxconfig 
You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
6.0.18r136238
```

i have tried step 1

```
sudo /sbin/vboxconfig
```

output below

> vboxdrv.sh: Stopping VirtualBox services.
>   vboxdrv.sh: Starting VirtualBox services.
>   vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
>   This system is currently not set up to build kernel modules.
>   Please install the gcc make perl packages from your distribution.
>   This system is currently not set up to build kernel modules.
>   Please install the gcc make perl packages from your distribution.
>   There were problems setting up VirtualBox.  To re-start the set-up process, run
>     /sbin/vboxconfig
>   as root.  If your system is using EFI Secure Boot you may need to sign the
>   kernel modules (vboxdrv, vboxnetflt, vboxnetadp, vboxpci) before you can load
>   them. Please see your Linux system's documentation for more information.

step 2 :

```
sudo /usr/lib/virtualbox/vboxdrv.sh setup
vboxdrv.sh: Stopping VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Starting VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
This system is currently not set up to build kernel modules.
Please install the gcc make perl packages from your distribution.
```

after i have install library with command 
`sudo apt-get install build-essential gcc make perl dkms`
 but still not working . kernel vboxdrv still not loaded. somebody helpme .

Answer (score 2):

I met the same issue and the following commands sequence helped for me:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall virtualbox-dkms
sudo modprobe vboxdrv
```

Comment: I dont have modprobe !! What this ?